# Change order of derived properties in Matlab

Tags: matlab, oop

Let's say I have two classes foo and bar:

```
classdef foo
    properties
        prop1;
        prop2;
    end
end



classdef bar < foo
    properties
        prop3;
        prop4;
    end
end
```

If I initialize bar, I get the following:

```
b = 

  bar with properties:

    prop3: []
    prop4: []
    prop1: []
    prop2: []
```

Is there a way to change the order of the properties such that they appear in order (prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4)?

Comment: yes you can customize [object display](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/custom-object-display.html). Specifically see this example: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/use-cases.html

Comment: Yes, I've seen that. However, that would assume that I already know the class structure, wouldn't it? Is it possible to have it appear in order when calling properties(bar)?

Comment: I assume you don't want lexicographic order, but base-class followed by derived class properties, right? Perhaps you can use introspection using [`metaclass`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/metaclass.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Amro I was able to come up with a solution that works. It may not be the cleanest way to do it, but it appears to work. I've made a class:

```
classdef CustomPropertyOrder
methods
    function propList = properties(obj)

        % Get info about the class
        classInfo = metaclass(obj);

        % Skip if it's the CustomPropertyOrder class
        if ~strcmp(classInfo.Name, 'CustomPropertyOrder')

            % Get list of superclasses
            superclassList = [classInfo.SuperclassList];

            % Get list of all properties
            allPropertyList = [classInfo.PropertyList];

            % Get list of the classes which define each property
            defPropertyList = [allPropertyList.DefiningClass];

            % Get the names of the properties
            propertyNameList = {allPropertyList.Name};

            % Get the defining classes of the properties
            propertyClassList = {defPropertyList.Name};

            % Get just the properties defined by the current class
            myProperties = propertyNameList(strcmp(propertyClassList, classInfo.Name))';

            % Loop through all the superclasses
            for idx = 1:length(superclassList)

                % Create an instance of the superclass
                f = str2func(superclassList(idx).Name);
                t = f();

                % Get the properties of the superclass
                supProperties = properties(t);

            end

            % Concat the property lists, putting the superclass properties
            % first
            propList = [supProperties; myProperties];

        else

            % Return an empty property list
            propList = [];

        end

    end
end
```

end

And I derive from this class whenever I need the properties to appear in the order I need.